# ISP Call center "user without internet" solution?

Tags: untagged

ive got this situation:
Operator pickups phone in helpdesk. By CallerID he gets users contract number and can see personal details.
Main question from user is "I dont have internet connection or i cant view web-sites"

Main Page:

1. MAC
2. IP
3. Ping results (his and neighbourhoods)
4. Type of connection (raidolink/LAN/WiFi)
5. Account Ballance (+10$/-2$/Disconnected)
6. First/Last/Middle Name, Contact Phone
7. CallerID

Second Page:

1. List of calls before

What else shoud operator know to determine whats problem user has (or if there any problems with conenction to that user) without asking any questions to user?

And what common questions for user are? Like any router/computer is powered on/ etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first page:

- Any currently outstanding incident
  tickets for that user.
- Any known
  problems that may be affecting that
  user.
- Any user "flags" - common
  account statuses that might be
  relevant to the account handler in
  dealing with the customer

Comment: Ok, and what else should know operator about network - status?

Comment: Ah, sorry, "known problems" is a technical term from ITIL, which is (among other things) a service desk/helpdesk management methodology. Known problems would include *relevant* network status.

Answer (score 8):

Well, some link error statistics have proven to be useful for troubleshooting, but to really ***know*** what the user's problem is, this would surely be the most valuable tool:

[image: soothsayer with glass ball]

You would need to provide more details on the typical problem range the helpdesk operators are meant to solve in order to get meaningful answers, as only few people here will capable of telepathy or soothsaying.

Comment: Ive edited my question, it is now more specific now.

Comment: Well the answer is still "it depends". Do you have your own infrastructure or do you just authenticate dialins and provide IP connectivity? Do you rent out modems or routers that are under your control? You would need a concise **list** of problems that your helpdesk should be able to solve - then you can derive questionnaires and resolution steps from there on. If your helpdesk should also be able to troubleshoot things, there is no sense in forbidding questions - if no questions were needed, you would be able to see and resolve a problem before a user calls in in the first place.

Comment: it is a lot of trouble to monitore all users. we can monitore some valuable nods. All network equipments is ours. We've already have Nagios system.